# How to configure Drupal module Commerce Shipping Weight Tariff?

Tags: rules, commerce

Due to a missing how-to in the module, i am stuck implementing Drupals [Commerce Shipping Weight Tariff](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping_weight_tariff) module.
I added some weight tariff services and under /admin/commerce/config/shipping/methods I added methods to the shipping matrix. Also i added a physical field for the weight to my products.
And here i am stuck: what's next thing to do?
Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Is it not listing the services when you are going through the shipping portion of checkout?

Comment: Thanks for asking: i didn't grok, that this module works out-of-the-box! I was searching and searching in the rules admin section for corresponding rules & components and didn't realise, that everything is working fine.

Comment: Awesome! There are some folks out there who write some great modules. joachim is one of those folks. Glad you got it working.